# How to resize an Office.js content Add-in programmatically?

Tags: xml, office-js

Setting up the initial size for an Office.js content Add-in is simple using its manifest's DefaultSettings.

```
  <DefaultSettings>
    <RequestedWidth>700</RequestedWidth>
    <RequestedHeight>476</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
```

I know that these add-ins can be resized manually by the user later on, but can you set the width and height of a content add-in programmatically after it is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RequestedWidth` and `RequestedHeight` can be set only through manifest. Office.js API doesn't provide functionality to resize programmatically content window. As you notice correctly user able to resize add-in window after invoking.